# How to read the xml part from json file in python3?

Tags: json, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have below json with xml file. I am looking for a solution to extract the xml part and traverse xml attribute using python 'ElementTree' or any other liberary ..

```
{
   "Data":{
      "myevent":{
         "payload":"<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>",
         "meta_data":{
            "Env":"l1-7",
            "EventName":"myEventName",
            "Source":"mysource",
            "Hash":"myhash",
            "PayloadKey":"mypayload",
            "ByteSize":300,
            "EventTim":"myTime",
            "Entity":"myEntity",
            "version":"myVersion"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now i want to extract the "payload" value as a xml, so i can traverse it  for further transformation using python ElementTree liberary

Appreciated if anybody can help on this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the `payload` (the XML), you can just index the data as you normally do in Python for dicts. This will give you a Python string. Then, you can pass it to the `fromstring` method so that you can traverse it.

**Example:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = {
   "Data":{
      "myevent":{
         "payload":"<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>",
         "meta_data":{
            "Env":"l1-7",
            "EventName":"myEventName",
            "Source":"mysource",
            "Hash":"myhash",
            "PayloadKey":"mypayload",
            "ByteSize":300,
            "EventTim":"myTime",
            "Entity":"myEntity",
            "version":"myVersion"
         }
      }
   }
}

tree = ET.fromstring(data['Data']['myevent']['payload'])
for element in tree:
    print(element.text)
```